# deployJava script fails in Chrome browser

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, version

I am trying to use the [deployJava script](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) from Oracle to check the installed java version. It works fine on FireFox but fails in Chrome, as when i test java version 1.6 it always returns false which means i have a java version below 1.6, which is not right. I've seen some forums mentioning this problem, but i have found no fix for this until now.

Anyone has checked this script before ?

---------------------------------------------------> **Edit - Add a code sample :**

```
var isJavaValid = deployJava.versionCheck( '1.6.0+' );

if( isJavaValid == false ) {
   alert( "Java required version is not found" );  // Always appears.
}
else {
   alert( "You have the right java version." );
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example code?

Comment: @Tyilo: Please check the above code.

Comment: Works fine with me (google chrome canary and dev channel). Have you imported "http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js" correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init()
{
var isJavaValid = deployJava.versionCheck( "1.6.0+" );

if( isJavaValid == false ) {
   alert( "Java required version is not found" );  // Always appears.
}
else {
   alert( "You have the right java version." );
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
</body>
</html>
```

Test here: http://jsbin.com/ikiza4

Comment: This is so strange ! I've just made copy/paste to your code in a new html page, and it still returns "false" in Chrome, while in your test in jsbin it returns true ! In FireFox both return true !!!